# SQL Server 2008 r2 TempDB data file is not releasing space back to OS

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2, tempdb, dbcc

Temp db data file is not clearing or deallocating space to OS after DBCC CheckDB "myDB" process completed successful. I used SP_WhoIsActive script to diagnose and found out DBCC CheckDB process is causing temp db growth but it is only happening for one database which is about 16 GB that DBCC CheckDB is using temp db as i have seen using SP_WhoIsActive.

Note: When I restart SQL Server tempdb will release allocated space to OS but will grown to 45 GB after DBCC Check DB job runs and doesn't deallocate used space.

Comment: The tempdb is just that...temporary. SQL Server will take it back to its default size upon restart. In general the guidance is to not shrink tempdb because auto expansion is an expensive operation. see https://technet.microsoft.com/en-US/library/ms175527(v=SQL.105).aspx and https://technet.microsoft.com/en-US/library/ms345368(v=SQL.105).aspx

Comment: @Jeremy There is a table with 20 million row counts and has one non clustered index - do you think that might be the reason since DBCC Checkdb includes index? Thanks

Comment: If you read the second article, one of the things that uses tempdb space is the DBCC CHECKDB command. If you have the disk space, leave tempdb alone. It will settle at a size it is happy with, however if you read the articles again, you'll see you can set an initial size for tempdb so it doesn't have to regrow to the size it wants to be when you reboot SQL Server.